# gmapping+depthimage_to_laser, Scan must contain angles from -x to x

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, xtion, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

Problem with depthimage_to_laserscan and gmapping:

I got my Asus Xtion Pro (no RGB) up and running on ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04. Now, I try to create LaserScan messages from the depthimage and use it for Gmapping. What i do is: I launch the `openni2.launch` and then `depthimage_to_laserscan` node. **I can see the visualization of the LaserScan under the /scan topic in Rviz perfectly.** But when i modify and launch my gmapping launch file (which works fine with an actual lidar), i start getting tons of repeating errors:

```
[ERROR] [1446110574.405766241]: Scan message must contain angles from -x to x, i.e. angle_min = -angle_max
```

and of course gmapping does not work. Topics and everything are correct. It must be directly related to how `depthimage_to_laserscan` works. Could not figure it out myself,

Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220085/gmapping+depthimage_to_laser,-scan-must-contain-angles-from--x-to-x/) by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I researched more and tried different suggested solutions and it turned out that the problem was being caused by a bug in the 1.3.7 gmapping release. thanks to @stevenwaslander answer, the fix for the problem that i explained in my question above, is as follows:

```
$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-gmapping/ros-indigo-gmapping_1.3.8.orig.tar.gz
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ tar xvf ../../ros-indigo-gmapping_1.3.8.orig.tar.gz   
$ mv ros-indigo-gmapping-1.3.8/ gmapping
$ catkin_make
$ sudo cp devel/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping* /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gmapping/
```

---

Originally posted by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) with karma: 75 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0